# Car just clicks when starting, and turns off while running

Tags: starting, intrepid

I have a 2004 Intrepid 2.7l V6.  I had to replace the starter last year for a similar issue.  Now when I turn the key it does nothing.  The radio comes on etc, but there's no noise from the engine.  If I turn it a couple of times in rapid succession and then wait a few seconds and try it again, I can usually get it to start. It seems to happen more frequently if I've driven somewhere and then left it for a few minutes and try to start it again, like the store etc. Today it died twice while I was driving home.  The engine just cut out and I had to put it in park and start it up again.

Could it be the starter again?  Alternator?  What should I check?

Comment: Welcome to the site. It sounds like the ignition switch may be going out of it, but that'd just be a guess. It's the cutting off while driving and it working after several rapid succession attempts which leads me to this thought.

Comment: I agree with what @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 says. The alternator can be ruled out, same for the starter at least for now. When the engine cuts off, does the ignition stays at "on"? that is, what lights do you see on the instrument panel?

Comment: Listen to Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 and Aus also check the battery and please DO NOT DRIVE IT ANYMORE, cutting off while running is dangerous and should be avoided

Answer (score -1):

That sounds like the battery is empty or the alternator has got a charge problem. A friend of mine had a similar problem. Some ob his cables from then alternator to the battery were loose and after he replaced those cables and started the engine with a jumpstarter. Now its running good. Check the baterry while you start the engine, check the alternator and of course check the sparkplugs, maybe the are broken and they are not able to spark. I hope it helps you!!!

Comment: If this were a dead battery, how could she "*...turn it a couple of times in rapid succession and then wait a few seconds and try it again, I can usually get it to start*"? It also doesn't address the engine shutting off while driving. Are you just answering the title and not the whole question?

Comment: This should not be related to battery, and I don't think a battery can get charged or give more voltage because of few cranks. Even a fully charged battery can provide only few number of cranks.

Answer (score -1):

The issue could be battery or alternator, but could also be starter or starter relay. If it is making no sound at all, but the radio and headlights can come on (without the headlights being dim at all), I would think its an issue with the starter or starter relay, maybe check to see if all of your connections between those and the battery are there and not corroded and then go from there?

Comment: We had a Rover 820 that had a similar issue, where it would start but then die when in motion (30mph and it'd konk out!). It was down to a dodgy relay switch in some of the electronics. You would hear a clicking sound then it'd die.